# WCF Synchronous vs Asynchronous

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, asynchronous

I have been looking at MSDN and codeproject, but I am still a bit confused.

Synchronous Service vs an Asynchronous service.

I have a WCF service end point. This service has a 2way SSL applied to its web.config file.
The client end point is a Oracle based java Weblogic Suite. This has its own private key and public key. The client needs to communicate with our service both asynchronously and synchronously.

**I CAN ONLY CHANGE THINGS ON THE SERVER SIDE**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91528/How-to-Call-WCF-Services-Synchronously-and-Asynchr

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

The following code is the synchronous part of the SVC, cs file:-

```
public getQuoteSyncResponse1 getQuoteSync(getQuoteSyncRequest request)
     {
        // Create new response
        getQuoteSyncResponse1 res = new getQuoteSyncResponse1();

        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse = new GetQuoteSyncResponse();
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Header = new GetQuoteResponseHeaderType();
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Response = new GetQuoteSyncResponseType();

        // Create and populate header
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Header.MessageId = request.GetQuoteRequestSync.Header.MessageId;
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Header.Timestamp = request.GetQuoteRequestSync.Header.Timestamp;
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Header.QuoteId = request.GetQuoteRequestSync.Header.QuoteId;
        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Header.CarrierId = request.GetQuoteRequestSync.Header.CarrierId;


        List<RejectionType> rj = new List<RejectionType>();


        string _sTotalEmployees = request.GetQuoteRequestSync.Request.Employer.TotalEmployees;
        int _TotalEmployees = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(_sTotalEmployees, out _TotalEmployees) == false)
        {


            RejectionType rt;
            rt = new RejectionType();
            rt.ReasonCode = "R01";
            rt.ReasonDescription = "Invalid Number of Employees";

            rj.Add(rt);

            res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Response.Rejections = rj.ToArray();

            res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Response.ReceiptStatus = AcceptanceContentType.Reject;

            return res;
        }

        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Response.ReceiptStatus = AcceptanceContentType.Success;

        List<QuoteType> q = new List<QuoteType>();

        QuoteType qt;

        qt = new QuoteType();
        qt.PlanId = "P345678";
        qt.EEPremium = 1220;
        qt.EESPPremium = 2222;
        qt.EEDepPremium = 3333;
        qt.EEFamilyPremium = 4444;
        qt.TotalMonthlyPremium = 3456;
        qt.CoverageEffectiveDate = DateTime.Now;

        q.Add(qt);

        res.GetQuoteSyncResponse.Response.Quotes = q.ToArray();

        return res;}
```

so this Synchronous part of the service is working. Now, how do I use this to transform it into the asynchronous equivalent?

Should I be starting the async method in the cs file? or in the svc file? I am confused...

```
 public getQuoteAsyncResponse getQuoteAsync(getQuoteAsyncRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    {
        // Create new response
        getQuoteAsyncResponse res = new getQuoteAsyncResponse();

        return new getQuoteAsyncResponse();
    }
```

I sort of understand about the callback deli-gator, object state and such, but can someone illustrate this further for me? How do I format the asynchronous part of the service? The web has so many examples... but all very confusing. I must have some inherent misunderstanding on this concept.

***Edit:- I was told in the answer that, the server side needs no manipulation for async style of communication. However I found this:-***

Implementing Asynchronous Operations in WCF 
Just as the WCF plumbing enables clients to call server operations asynchronously, without the server needing to know anything about it, WCF also allows service operations to be defined asynchronously. So an operation like:

```
[OperationContract]
string DoWork(int value);
```

…might instead be expressed in the service contract as:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
IAsyncResult BeginDoWork(int value, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

string EndDoWork(IAsyncResult result);
```

Note that the two forms are equivalent, and indistinguishable in the WCF metadata: they both expose an operation called DoWork[1]:

Answer (score 1):

The async part needs to be done in the client. This means you are probably doing something similar to:
var response = ServiceReference.GetSomething();

Instead, make a proxy to get the callback. Create and event (or delegate) that gets fired (or called) whenever the callback receives the response. In the above statement, you are obviously waiting for the response to be assigned into the variable before moving to the next line.

Instead, you could

1. On the Service contract, be sure to decorate with [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
2. If you use ServiceReference or serviceutil, it will automatically create "incoming events" and do all the client side async work for you.
3. If you are using TCP, create an callback contract as well, then on client you can do something like 
   ServiceReference1.IncomingSomething += new eventHandler.
   Now you can do ServiceReferecnce1.GetSomething(), and the response will go to the eventhandler function.
4. If this is RESTFUL:

   ```
     public void MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                       request.ContentType = contentType;
                       request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                       request.Timeout = 10000;
                       request.Proxy = null;

                       request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       LogManager.LogException(ex);
                   }
               }

               private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
               {
                   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                   string strContent = string.Empty;
                   string s;

                   try
                   {
                       using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                       {
                           Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                           {
                               //Need to return this response 
                               strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       throw;
                   }
               }
   ```

Comment: just to add a few more comments:-

>> yes, this is a RESTful service.
>> yes, this is TCP oriented communicaton.
>> I cannot add anything on the client side, the client side is un-handled by me. The only thing I can co-ordinate with the client is the 2way SSL communication, RESTful Soap XML packages and the data structure of the packages.


So the code you added is it on the client side or the server side?

Comment: You are understanding the code right, meaning it is done on the client side. You **can not** have async/sync logic in the service. It must be done on the client side.

Comment: For example, if the client does _var response = ServiceReference.GetSomething();_ it will not matter what you do on the service side because the client will wait for the response before moving to the next line. It is up to the **client design pattern** to use services sync or async.

Comment: hmmm.... well, the client is built by someone else. I don't have any part to play on that part of the coding. I posted my code from the server side. Is there anything that needs to be implemented on the server side to make it async compatible with the client side?

Comment: nope. In this case there is nothing that you can do. There is no design pattern on the service side that cares about sync/async. It all in the client. Since you don't play any part in the client, there is nothing more that you can do.

Comment: hmm... can I send the client a call back ID? some kind of an ID number on which the client can co-relate a later response from the service? I mean the whole point of async to me is that, hey i am the client, can i access ur service? hey I m the server, it will take me some time, here is your ID#, when I send you my response, i will append the ID# with the response so that you know which question I am responding to... in the meanwhile u can ask me new questions and so can other clients and ya'll can be free to do whatever u want// no hold ups. right ?